# Loop for click event in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have multiple text boxes on a form and I want to display the name of the textbox when I click on it in a specific textbox. As I have 300 textboxes I dont want to create 300 click Events. Do I need some kind of loop?

Comment: You can add events programmatically using a loop. Post some more code for more details.

Comment: in wpf or in window form

Comment: Do you work with `WinForms`, `WPF` or something else?

Comment: How were the textboxes created? From code or from the designer? If they were created from code, you can assign all of the click events to one handler and from the handler, simply cast `sender` to a textbox and get its name. If they were created from the designer, select all the textboxes on the form , go to the events tab,  double click on the click events to generate one event for all the textboxes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, exactly, iterate through all your `Controls` on your `Form` and if `Control` **is a** `TextBox`, subscribe to an event like this:

```
private void subScribeAllTextBoxClickEvents()
{
  foreach(var ctrl in this.Controls)
  {
    var textBox = ctrl as TextBox;
    if(textBox != null)
    {
      textBox.Click += textBox_Click;
    }
  }
}

private void textBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

You could call `subScribeAllTextBoxClickEvents` method for example in your constructor.

Comment: Inside textBox_Click event you can reach textbox's ID with ((TextBox)sender).ID

Comment: Or just `foreach(var ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>) ctrl.Click += textBox_Click;`

Comment: This will need to be done after the call to `InitializeComponent` (assuming Win forms) because the controls will not exist on the form until then.